# How can I prevent my longboard from sliding under me, into the road/pavement

Tags: technique, skateboarding

I am new to longboarding/skateboarding. I have picked up the basics and am able to ride confidently. However, sometime I tend to lose balance and the board slides from under my foot and goes ahead of me or behind me depending on how I lose balance. When this happens, the board just darts and wont stop for a significant distance. I am afraid the board might hit somebody's foot or worse, go into the road. Is there anyway to prevent it. I have a silly idea of tying a twine or something similar to it and hooking to up to my bag/pants, but I don't want to look silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally accepted solution is to accept that this will happen - you can minimise the risk by kicking the board backward when you bail, but most skaters would rather damage the board than accidentally get hooked up with a leash in traffic, or trip on the leash when trying to bail at speed etc. Boards are meant to take dings anyway.

That said, there are some situations when you might want one, so you can use a leash (a little like a surfer's leash, but tightly coiled so it won't go under the trucks, hopefully) but you will look silly and will get harassed by other skaters :-)

There was someone who invented a 'dead man's brake' that would stop a longboard quite quickly if your foot came off it, but it didn't catch on.